# How can I create a runnable JAR file with Maven + JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx

I going to create a runnable JAR file inside Eclipse IDE. All my dependencies are from Maven. In Eclipse I'm creating a JavaFX GUI application for desktop.

The problem is that when I creating the runnable JAR file. I got this error.

[image]

The error is very clear.

> Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional
>   information.   Could not find main method from given launch
>   configuration.

But what is main method? Is it the `public static void main(String[] args)` method here?

What should I do to solve this?

```
package se.danielmartensson.start;

import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import se.danielmartensson.concurrency.Measureing;

public class Main extends Application{

    /*
     * Start the start(Stage front)
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage front) throws Exception {
        front.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
            e.consume();
            askForClosing();
        });
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/se/danielmartensson/fxml/front.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        front.setScene(scene);
        front.setTitle("JUBSPlotter");      
        front.show();
    }

    private void askForClosing() {
        Alert question = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        question.setTitle("Closing");
        question.setHeaderText("Do you want to close?");
        question.setResizable(false);
        question.setContentText("Press OK to close.");
        Optional<ButtonType> answer = question.showAndWait();
        if(answer.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            Measureing.active = false;
            Platform.exit();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at this question: [Maven Shade JavaFX runtime components are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing). Simply Eclipse -> Export won't work, and if you are already using Maven, the best option is the shade plugin. Alternatively, if your project is modular, you can use the JavaFX-Maven-plugin and `javafx:jlink` as explained [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse), section Modular with Maven.

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks. Now it's to much. I think I will start with your answer :)

Comment: The error message is saying the manifest file is missing, the maven-jar-plugin will create this if you use the jar:jar goal.

Comment: @MartinSpamer How? jar:jar goal? A command? Where to input?

Comment: @MartinSpamer Ok! I put the "jar:jar" command in the Build Maven window and build it. But still, I cannot create an exe JAR file.

Comment: Look in the target folder, is there any jar file?  If there is, open it with any tool that will open zip files and see if it contains a manifest.mf file.  Make sure that contains a Main-Class entry with the fully qualified name of your Main class.

Comment: @MartinSpamer Yes. I can see a JAR-file now and I can open it :) But to bad it missing Maven dependencies. So the JAR file is full of errors .

Comment: @MartinSpamer I think I will use Maven assembly instead of jar:jar

Comment: Either maven-assembly-plugin or maven-shade-plugin is the correct way to create an executable jar.

Comment: @khmarbaise So what is the correct way? I have seen many different ways to create JAR files with maven. That's the reason in my opinion I think Maven is kind of a mess, because it's no standard way or only-one-way to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the following maven plugin to create a runnable jar file.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.ddlab.rnd.App
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This is for very simple project where you want to learn about how to create an executable jar file to run. 
To have a good idea about how to create a runnable/executable jar file, check this github link.
https://github.com/debjava/runnableJar
If you have other libraries to use as part of your application. You have to create fat jar file. To create a fat jar file, you have to use Maven Shade plugin. Find below the link for maven shade plugin.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: Did not work if I add this code-text into the pom.xml file.

Comment: Post your pom.xml, Let me check,I will try to add.

Comment: It seams that Maven have stopped working for me. Cannot download any dependencies...

Comment: Check your internet connectivity.

Comment: Ofc I have internet  ;)

Comment: Change the main class, You have added like this com.ddlab.rnd.App. This is from the example, change your class having main method.

Comment: Ok! I have change it now to my main class. IStill not working due to the maven won't download. I don't know happen. It worked yesterday.

Comment: Check it in ofc, may be maven is unable to connect, otherwise post the maven error.

Comment: I will check it, then come back and give a reply of the result.

Comment: Now Maven is working. I just deleted the .m2 folder. But I still get the same error: "Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
  Could not find main method from given launch configuration.
".

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Have added that maven-jar-plugin, packaged again, i see my main class defined in manifest.mf file in META-INF in packaged .jar, but still get same error: Could not find or load main class. Did you solve this issue? Any tips?